# Does using the Fence API in the Background require a Foreground Service in Android P

Tags: android, google-awareness, android-9.0-pie

With Android P, apps running in the background will no longer receive sensor updates. One way around this will be using a Foreground Service.

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes)

> Limited access to sensors in background
>
> Android P limits the ability for background apps to access user input and sensor data. If your app is running in the background on a device running Android P, the system applies the following restrictions to your app:

- > Your app cannot access the microphone or camera.
- > Sensors that use the continuous reporting mode, such as accelerometers and gyroscopes, don't receive events.
- > Sensors that use the on-change or one-shot reporting modes don't receive events.

> If your app needs to detect sensor events on devices running Android P, use a foreground service.

Does this also apply to indirect sensor access like through the Awareness/Fence  API? Do they need a foreground service as well?

Comment: Did you figure out if it applies to fence api?

Comment: It has been a while and I've stopped working with mobile tech since then, but I believe to remember that it worked.